# Java program to sign pdf files fails when executing it with php exec from the web browser

Tags: java, php, pdf, exec

I use a java program to stamp and sign pdf files from the a php web. I run it with php's exec function and all works great with small files but when I try to sign pdf files heavier than 60mb it crashes and outputs nothing. Normally when it fails because of a java problem prints error messages, but this time it outputs nothing and the pdf is created with 0 bytes.

If I run the java program directly on the server or execute the php script on the server with the php command works fine. The problem occurs only on the web browser.

Anyone can help me to find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd argument of php's exec() function allows you to specify output. You could then var_dump() this variable to see what errors are being encountered.

Comment: how much time that it takes to sign a pdf greater than 60mb ? also, can you show us the content of error.log ?

Comment: @GoatMaster I knew that, but it prints an empty array...

Comment: @HalayemAnis in the logs doesn't appear nothing... To sign a pdf the program can take from seconds to four or five minutes, but I have increased the php max_execution_time to ten minutes, the problem isn't the time because it fails in few seconds.

Comment: add this in top of your PHP script, hope that en error or warning will be displayed or logged :
error_reporting(E_ALL);
Also, can you share with us your PHP code ?

Comment: I added the `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but no errors messages are shown... This is my code:

`<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
exec('java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar program.jar -in:input.pdf -out:output.pdf -config:config_file.xml', $output, $return);
var_dump($output, $return);
?>`

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem comes from your web server configuration. See the `upload_max_filesize` property in your php.ini and change the limit.

`upload_max_filesize = 100M` for example

You can also modify this property :

```
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: he's not talking about upload file, but executing a process launched via web browser

Comment: He said "I use a java program to stamp and sign pdf files from the a php web" then it may be an upload ...

Comment: @HalayemAnis is right, I don't upload the file, is already on the server.